# Drawing some elements over others on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing

I have a list of figures, which have different coefficients. I would like to draw figures with a higher coefficient above those that have it lower. How can I effectively accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set their [`Panel.ZIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) property, which

> Gets or sets a value that represents the order on the z-plane in which
>   an element appears

You may bind the ZIndex to the Coefficient property of your view model:

```
<Polyline Points="{Binding Figure}" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding Coefficient}" .../>
```

Comment: My figures are `Polyline` objects, and they don't have `ZIndex` property which will probably solve the problem. One solution would be to first draw polylines with smaller coefficients then those which have it greater, but in this approach there will be large overhead for processing because the list is big(hundreds of thousands objects) and that's why I am looking for another solution.

Comment: `Panel.ZIndex` is an attached property. It can be set on any UI element, including Polylines.